# Page looks different in iPad view - CSS issue

Tags: css, ipad

I have an issue on [this page](http://pwtest.iurecsports.org) when I open it on iPad. Crimson colored top identification header goes to left and then on the right side you can see a blank space. All other major browsers including Safari shows the page as it should be except iPad. Here's the screen shot from [iPad view](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/401/photouu.png/). Any ideas whats wrong with it?

Comment: Please don't use URL shortening services in your question.

Comment: okey, fixed now. thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content in your #signature div is bigger than your #signature div, so the background isn't stretching to fit the content (you can get the same reaction by shrinking the size of your window and scrolling to the left or right).

Fixes:

- Remove `left: -5px;` from #signature a.iu
- Add `background: #7D110C` to #signature
- Change `right: 0` on #signature form to `right: 5px`.

That should straighten things up.

**EDIT**

Here's what your updated styles should look like.

```
#identity #signature {
    height: 44px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 990px;
    background: #7D110C;
}

#identity #signature a.iu {
    background: url(pw_files/img/iu_crimson.gif) no-repeat 20px 0;
    display: block;
    height: 44px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
}

#identity form {
    height: 44px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
}
```

I pulled these styles out of [screen.css](http://pwtest.iurecsports.org/pw_files/css/screen.css)

Comment: Could you please see if I changed them right, because it is still same.

Comment: It still looks the same to me as well, but I also don't see any changes in the CSS. See my updated answer for my information.

Comment: I believe it is identical to your edited css. Still does not work for me.

Comment: Change #signature to `width: 1000px`. That fixed the issue I saw from resized the browser window at least. I don't have access to an iPad right now to confirm it however.

Comment: It solved the issue of top header, you are right! Thank you! However, there are still like extra 5px left on the right side as a whole - do not know why.

Comment: Your `#footer` has a padding that's extending the width. Try changing it to `padding-top: 5px`.

Comment: Also, there is an empty space which is a div on top of the dog picture which I can not remove. Do you have any clue how may I take care of it?

Comment: Is your delete button broken?

Comment: padding-top: 5px worked, thank you very much! could you please explain why it worked?

Comment: My delete button? What do you mean? That I cannot delete div? :)) it is generated automatically, so when I edit it, I do not see it :))

Comment: If you define a width (1000px) and a padding (5px) you are essentially adding 5px onto either side of the div, so your real width is 1010px. padding-top just applies the padding to the top of your footer, which is where you wanted the gap to be. Can't you just delete the div out of the HTML?

Comment: That is the problem, I do not see that line.

Comment: It's not a div. You have a table layout (I highly recommend you don't do table layouts). It's all screwed up. I wish I could help you, but I don't know where to start. I can tell you the problem areas are the second and third tr in your main table. You're going to want to get everything that lines up horizontally on the same tr.

Comment: Changed height of these:`<td height="5" colspan="4" align="left" valign="top">

      <table width="639" height="0" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`

Answer (score 1):

First off, it looks like you have the university logo in the upper left set as both a background image and a regular image within the `<a>`. Removing the regular image fixes the problem seen in both your iPad screenshot and in my desktop browser where the logo is cut off on the left and "ity" repeats in "University".

I don't have an ipad in front of me, but it's possible that might fix the problem with the right space as well. You might want to consider adding a `margin-right` to the form in the header so the "Go" button isn't right up against the edge of the window at `1024px` resolution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had totally missed it. Fixed it now, thank you very much!